# Two action after then in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Is it possible to make two actions after a then in Ocaml ?
I try to search and I found that I could use a semicolon. 
Should I use it like this ? :

```
let test (a:int)=
if a = 0
then print_int(1);print_int(2)
else()
;;
```

It's just an example. In my case I want to launch a function and give a tuple like that :

```
let move_square(x,y:int*int):int*int=
..
let direction : int = Random.int(5);
if direction = 0
then draw_square(x,y+1);x,y+1
else ..
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to §Séquence of https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/qrg-fra.html.

Generally you have to group ocaml statement in an if-then-else structure,
either by using explicitly `begin`and `end` keywords, or by using parenthesis to group your sequence.

Comment: For non-French speakers, the translation of the FAQ is at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/qrg-eng.html